# How to expicitly load only specific (not all) css files in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I want to develop a usual website with Meteor.js (not one-page web app) and I want to load only specific css files for every page. So not all pages share the same css code.
Is it possible?

Comment: This is not recommended - it will make your app slower. The best practice currently is to concatenate all of your website's CSS into one file.

Comment: This is not true for every case, since it depends on the size of CSS of a website. CSS loading process blocks page rendering. So if you have few CSS it will be better to load it fully or even inline it. But if you have much CSS it is better to load first CSS necessary for rendering only one page or even only above-the-fold content and defer loading of the remaining styles. More information you can find here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @Eugene hook me up with some points and accept an answer please :)

Answer (score 11):

First off if you are using Meteor you are not building a "usual" site, you are building a very powerful SPA (single page application). You can imitate a "usual" website with introducing routing, try [IronRouter](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router).

OK now about CSS. Once you deploy Meteor all your CSS and JS are merged and minified. So if you want to achieve what you are asking you will need to add a package like this one.

https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/external-file-loader

https://github.com/davidd8/meteor-external-file-loader

Then attach it to trigger once a template is created:

```
Template.myCustomTemplate.created = function() {
  Meteor.Loader.loadCss("//example.com/myCSS/style.css");
};
```

I believe you could also load the CSS from the Meteor server through Meteor's Asset API. Read more here: https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets

Comment: A very short and accurate explanation of what Meteor really is! :) +1

Comment: but if we move back to the previous view your css is still loaded.That is css is not removed and therefore previous view css changesd.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution. In your meteor project folder create a folder named "public" (no quotes). In that folder create a folder called "css" (no quotes). Put the CSS file in that folder.

In the html file which you want the specific CSS file to apply to do the following:

```
<head>
<link href="css/yourfile.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the last part of your question says, "So not all pages share the same CSS code." you might consider using less and wrapping your template in a different div class.

For example

HTML file

```
<template name="page1">
    <div class="page1css">
        <p class="content">Page 1 content</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

LESS File

```
.page1css {
    .content {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

This way you can just wrap your pages and the corresponding css in the correct class.

Comment: This way still loads all the CSS for the whole app no matter which page is visited.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but it also only loads it once. Then it uses the specific CSS for the template after that. I wasn't sure what exactly Eugene was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I personally use the same concept to avoid overlaps between the styles for different templates. Although I recommend using IDs to differentiate. Template page1 would get an ID "view-page1" - I only need to remember not to use any ID starting with view- to avoid conflicts. Additionally you have a common.less file with shared styles. `meteor add less`

Comment: What if you have a css file for a custom theme, and you want that loaded on only one page? Modifying the class selectors would mean changing the class for each rule?

Comment: You can actually just use import now, so my answer isn't applicable for newer versions of Meteor (>1.3)