# MeteorJS: Selectively load javascript of each template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have notice that meteor is creating and loading every template javascript file. Is it possible to selectively load javascript of each template? Because my app generate template file for each of my user. So if this is the case every user's template javascript is loaded to the page. That would not be ideal.

*index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_cart.jade.js?4e6fe10676dcbfd5eec51f802ab604bf7afefdfc"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_footer.jade.js?c904832f29a144cc6a3c53b8fc4159088d427ce9"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_header.jade.js?02a4f5e9a4a697194e32a16bee9209fa9a63422a"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_home.jade.js?91d90f326d7da8db94396648b81f88c739691754"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_product.jade.js?3eed90e15d544fb8e4d5418c641a51ce94c048b2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/views/themes/jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa/plate_jnr8tWHJ6JTARPpYa_search.jade.js?08b0b0b4e02599e9ceaac00b94515a1ee7638036"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, yet, but is on the roadmap: [Incremental loading](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading). According to that card:

> Right now, on initial pageload, you download all of the JavaScript, templates, and css in the app.

If you are generating a unique file in your filesystem for every user that uses your app, you might want to reconsider how you are going about structuring your app. Do you really need a new template for every user, or can you get it done with one template and have it update according to which user is currently displayed/logged in?

Comment: I think this a big drawback for meteor. Even a simple app that has a front end and an admin pages as for now meteor will load all the js of the admin and the front end even you are just accessing the admin page or the way around is very inefficient.

Comment: Well generally all the javascript templates for a fairly large sized app still end up much smaller than a single image on your page, and most that javascript doesn't get run, so it's just a few KB extra download that you're unlikely to notice anyway. It's hardly a big drawback, but it could be improved, so it's on the roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you shouldn't.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694517/1523072) explains an elegant approach of selective loading and also explains why you shouldn't.

Consider the fact that after the initial page load (of maybe 2MB - 5MB for a medium size app) the browser caches everything and all that comes through the wire is pure data.