# Loading particular css file for particular page in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor

I have 3 pages say x,y,z and 3 CSS files c1,c2,c3

now if I want to include c1 and c2 CSS file for page x instead of including all three CSS files c1,c2 and c3.

How can we achieve that in meteor framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692452/how-to-expicitly-load-only-specific-not-all-css-files-in-meteor-js) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263232/how-to-conditionally-load-bundle-css-files-in-meteor-1-0), Meteor bundles all your CSS together at deploy-time, so to work around this you'll want to make the CSS opaque to Meteor and load it yourself. A quick and dirty way:

- Move your stylesheets to your project's `/public` folder ([more info here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp))
- Add `<script>` to each relevant template (say in x.html) to inject the CSS as desired:

  > `$(document).ready(
  >     $('head').append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='c1.css' type='text/css' />"))
  >   );`

You can achieve this without jQuery too, but in general, solutions like this won't be pretty and may cause UI flicker from late loading of the styles, so you should consider whether it's really necessary to work against the platform behavior in your app.